# C# GetFullPath behavior

Tags: c#

When I passed the drive letter to Path.GetFullPath method as following

```
string path = @"C:";
string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(path);
Console.WriteLine(fullPath);
```

I got the following output

```
C:\\Users\\mat.sa\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication3\\ConsoleApplication3\\bin\\Debug
```

I don't understand why GetFullPath returned the above result.
I thought it should be

```
C:
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how paths work, for historic reasons. `C:` refers to the C drive. `\` refers to the root directory, but you haven't specified that.

When the current directory is already on the C drive, `C:` doesn't need to change anything, so it just signifies whatever directory you were already in.

If the current directory *weren't* on the C drive, then `C:` would effectively resolve to `C:\`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
string path = @"C:\";
string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(path);
Console.WriteLine(fullPath);
```

Comment: This may fix the issue, but does not answer why the issue appears.